# dcm4chee outside local network access

Tags: java, dcm4che

I have a question for the DCM4CHEE experts.
The dcm4chee is working fine form our local network.
http://192.168.151.43:8080/dcm4chee-arc/ui2/
But i can not access to it from outside this local network.
The ip address of the machine is fixed.
When i enter the address like that :
http://195.141.14.173:8080
I have an answer from the server
But the full address there is an internal server error.

http://195.141.14.173:8080/dcm4chee-arc/ui2/

Do you have any odea how to fix that ?

Is there another port to open to access form outside ?

And do you know how to add multiple acess for multiple users ? I would like to give access for only some studies to external doctors.

Kind regards.
Antoine Adam

Comment: ISE's will usually print the error to the server log files, not to the client browser. Check you logs, d[edit] your post to include any relevant messages.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your questions in the google group of [dcm4chee](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dcm4che). Regarding to your question, you have to set your IP in KeyCloak as an valid URL, and set the same url (IP and Port) in the environment variable as AUTH_SERVER_URL.